# Can't rectify a condition in the right way when there are multiple nots involved

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to combine multiple not conditions in a single line but I can't make it. This is how the conditional statements should be built upon:

***when `stat` has a value and both the value of `alternative` and `successor` are nothing then only the script should print `true`.***

When I try the following, I get `true` as the result.

```
stat = "o"
alternative = ""
successor = ""

if stat and not (alternative and successor):
    print("true")
```

However, When I execute the following, I also get `true` as the result

```
stat = "o"
alternative = "p"
successor = ""

if stat and not (alternative and successor):
    print("true")
```

> How can I rectify the condition above to serve the purpose?

Comment: I think `(alternative or successor)` is what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> both the value of `alternative` and `successor` are nothing

This literally translates to

```
not alternative and not successor
```

By [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) it is equivalent to

```
not (alternative or successor)
```

Answer (score -1):

It this fit your purpose?

```
stat = "o"
alternative = ""
successor = ""

if (stat not None) and (alternative == None and successor == None):
    print("true")
```